# DaVinci Resolve 16 - Restore Deleted/Crushed Project

Tags: davinci-resolve

Hello again community!

I came back with a new issue in DaVinci Resolve 16.. I was working in two projects (both where opened) and after a crush both are lost. I restarted my PC just in case, but no I wasn't that lucky...

I have searched in AppData\Roaming\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\Support\Resolve Disk Database\Resolve Projects\user-name\Projects\MyProjects, but there weren't any trace from both of those.

I wasn't smart enough from the very beginning to set up the auto choice for creation projects' backups. (I did it know like shown in picture below).

[image: Auto Backup Preferences]

Logically there has to be a way to restore a deleted/crushed project in a tiny period of time (a couple of hours after that). Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you ever saved the project? If davinci doesn't show your project anywhere, I am afraid that it's lost. Regular saving should happen without noticing. Try to develop the habit of pressing ctrl+s every minute or so.

Comment: Yes I have the good habit to save it every 5-10 minutes. The project I have lost was successfully saved from yesterday. That's why I can not understand how a crash can delete it permanently.

Comment: Have you looked in C:\ProgramData\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\Support\Resolve Disk Database\Resolve Projects\. I am not sure why but that is where my projects are located.

Comment: My default location is AppData\Roaming\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\Support\Resolve Disk Database\Resolve Projects\user-name\Projects\MyProject, but those two projects are not there anymore..